# regex not fulfilling full condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently using regex to remove `www.` from any url entered into a text area. I ahve done this the following way:

```
var input = document.getElementById("tweet_text");
input.onkeyup = function() {
    input.value = input.value.replace(/www\.*/,"");
}
```

When a URL is copied and then pasted into the textarea, the regex does it's job.

If i was to manually enter a url it doesnt remove the `.`. I get to the last `w` and then the `www` gets removed allowing me to continue to type. Obviously the next character will be a `.` which will remain there, and end up with something like this:

```
http://.example.com
```

When it should look like this:

```
http://example.com
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because `.*` also matches an empty space (0 or more repetition). So, `www\.*` will successfully match `www`, and replace it. And then when you go on to type `.`, it won't match the pattern, and hence won't be replaced.

Try using `www\.+` or `www\.` instead:

```
input.value = input.value.replace(/www\.+/,"");
```

or:

```
input.value = input.value.replace(/www\./,"");
```

Comment: input.value = input.value.replace(/www\.+/,"") is good, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This replace function will work:

```
input.value = input.value.replace(/(^|\/)www\./i, "$1");
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the www to be at the beginning of a word.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're hooked into the onkeyup event. Change it to use onblur instead. That should fix your problem.